# What would be the most efficient way to check equality of a Firebase live database node value and also change it?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Above is what I have in my live database in Firebase. What I am trying to do is check if the current user's partyStatus is equal to the bool of false or true. And if it is false I want to change it to true.

This is what I tried so far:

```
usersReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  if snapshot.hasChild(uid) { 
    //continue another observeSingleEvent for the next value which is "partyStatus" then check the value then change it 
  }
```

How can I do this more efficiently with Firebase and Swift?

Comment: What have you tried that you believe to be inefficient?  There's not really very many ways to flip a bit.

Comment: @DougStevenson usersReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                
                if snapshot.hasChild(uid) {
                    //continue another observeSingleEvent for the next value which is "partyStatus" then check the value then change it
                }

Comment: @DougStevenson they way i did it was by nesting observeSingleEvent methods within each other for each node value but im positive there is an easier way but i just dont know what it is

Comment: OK, so edit your question to show the code you have, and see if anyone has an improvement that objectively benchmarks better.

Comment: Your updated code isn't actually showing how you find the boolean value and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code that could be used.

What we are doing here is examining the specific node in question for user_0, the partyStatus node. If it exists, get it's current value (assuming it's a bool) then toggle it (false to true or true to false) and if it doesn't exist, create it with a default value of false.

```
let ref = self.ref.child("users").child("user_0").child("partyStatus")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        let isPartying = snapshot.value as! Bool
        ref.setValue(!isPartying)
    } else {
        ref.setValue(false) //it doesn't exist to set to default of false
    }
})
//note that self.ref is a class var ref to my Firebase.
```

Answer (score 1):

You current code load the entire `usersReference` to then check if a single child exists in it.

A more efficient way to do the same check is to only load the reference for that user and then check if the snapshot exists:

```
usersReference.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  if snapshot.exists() { 
    if snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "partyStatus") as! Bool == false {
      usersReference.child(uid).child("partyStatus").setValue(true)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking to check a specific known existing, node.

Comment: Isn't that what my code does? I just extracted the `uid` from within the callback into the query, so that less data is loaded.

Comment: Nope. Your code looks to see if /users/uid exists. The OP wants to toggle the partyStatus node from true to false or false to true (I think)

Comment: Ah, you're a better reader than I am Jay! :-)    I updated my answer to do that change too. The difference between your an my answer is now mostly that I listen to the user node while you listen to the `partyStatus` node.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `runTransactionBlock` , Simply take the value , test , and return new value :

```
usersReference.child(uid).child("partyStatus").runTransactionBlock { (data) -> TransactionResult in
        let result = data
        // data = partyStatus value 

        if var value = data.value as? Bool {
           if value == false { // if value is false will change value to true in database
              value = true
              result.value = value 
           } // if not that mean the value is true and will return true
        }

        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: result)
    }
```

And for more information about `runTransaction` [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) .